# Refresh Spring ApplicationContext, without re-initializing context, possible?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I'm doing some integration tests with JUnit. I have an xml file where I declare some template entities which I want to inject. On every test, I need a fresh application context, that is no test should depend/couple with other tests, so on `setUp()` I need to 're-initialize' these entities on their default starting values.

I can achieve it through reloading, but this way I can't use `@Autowired` annotations.

```
@Before
public void setUp(){        
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:entityTemplates-Context.xml");
    homeA = (Home)ctx.getBean("homeA");
}
```

Is there a way to do this and still use `@Autowired` for these entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at Spring's support for integration testing?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

My team use this for our integration tests where we need a Spring container. You get a fresh context per test, though this slows down the tests significantly.

Comment: Thanks, I use spring-test too and after some sniffing just found '@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)', it does the job, it reloads the whole context, slow but only for integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it manually like this:

```
  ...
  @Autowired
  HomeA homeA;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    // configures this test instance as a regular spring bean
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);

    // here homeA is available
  }
  ...
```